# Custom dimension reporting not working - can see dimensions in tag manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track the internal campaigns on our website and followed the tutorial given by [Smashing Magazine](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/08/tracking-internal-marketing-campaigns-google-analytics/).

After implementing this, I was looking at the custom report and it is not showing any data. All it says is this - "There is no data for this view."

Attaching a screenshot from Tag Manager preview mode.

[image]

This is our [site](https://tribe.so) and I'm trying to track the buttons with custom parameters (itm_source, itm_medium, itm_campaign, itm_term, itm_content).

Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Do you add/set custom dimmensions in google analytics administration panel also for this account?

Comment: Yes, I've added. I have completely followed the article mentioned in my post.

Comment: Can you share with us how your report looks like? Do you published this changes on tribe.so? Cause i cant find any pageviews request with custom dimmensions in webdev/console on that site.

Comment: Since I didn't get any response, I removed these configurations and trying out another method.

P.S. The changes were published on the site and live.